# How to embed a dropdown ipywidget in an ipysheet spreadsheet?

Tags: python-3.x, dropdown, spreadsheet, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I tried following the code to merge a dropdown menu ipywidget into the ipysheet. it seems like my code works the way I imagined. However, I am unable to select items from the menus listed in the dropdown widget.

```
import ipysheet
import ipywidgets as widgets

Solvent = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['DMC', '2-Butanol', 'Chloroform', 'Ethanol'],
    value='DMC',)

sheet2 = ipysheet.sheet()
ipysheet.column(0, [Solvent])
ipysheet.column(1, [1,2,3,4, 5])


widgets.VBox([sheet2, Solvent ])
```

Answer (score 0):

After some review, I believe that this is a genuine bug/shortcoming with ipysheet. Though there are alternative approaches, this inability to use a particular widget within ipysheet cells is not an expected result of this API... Someone please correct me if I'm missing something.

There is a "hack" that is working for me through Jupyter Notebook in the browser, which is to right-click the dropdown before left-clicking it to change the context of the dropdown menu, allowing you to select it via mouseover.

[image: gif animation of right-click dropdown hack]

The other alternative is passing in your options as the "choice" argument to the *cell* you wish to contain the dropdown.

```
from ipywidgets import link
import ipysheet 
import ipywidgets as widgets

Solvent = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['DMC', '2-Butanol', 'Chloroform', 'Ethanol'],
    value='DMC',)

sheet2 = ipysheet.sheet()

# dropdown_cell = ipysheet.cell(0,0,choice = Solvent.options,value='WORLD')
interactive_cell = ipysheet.cell(1,3, value='HELLO')
dropdown_cell = ipysheet.cell(0,0,choice = Solvent.options,value='WORLD')

# link((interactive_cell,'value'),(dropdown_cell,'value'))
link((dropdown_cell,'value'),(interactive_cell,'value'))


widgets.VBox([sheet2, Solvent ])
```

From my current understanding (and attempts), only cells are interactive in ipysheets. (The alternative method of using [the ipysheet "calculation" decorator](https://ipysheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/ipysheet/easy.html#calculation) also depends on the items being Cells, not Columns.)